# Inno Setup Runtime error while accessing CurrentFileName when installing an empty folder

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I tried to access all files inside a folder through Pascal code. When I iterate through an empty folder I am getting the following error:

> Exception: Internal error; An attempt was made to call the "CurrentFileName" function from outside a "Check", "BeforeInstall" or "AfterInstall" event function belonging to a "[Files]" entry

The code I used:

```
[Files]
Source: ".\3D_Dlls\*"; DestDir: {app}\3D_Dlls; \
    Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs skipifsourcedoesntexist; \
    Check: FileBackup    

[Code]
function FileBackup(): Boolean; 
var FileName,Source,Target,TargetDir: String; 
begin 
  Result := True;
  Source := ExpandConstant(CurrentFileName);
end
```

Say for example my folder structure is like that:

```
3D_Dlls
-   Folder 1
-   Folder 2 // Empty folder and it invokes the problem
-   Folder 3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is a bug in Inno Setup triggered by the `createallsubdirs` flag.

When the flag is specified, Inno Setup collects a separate list of empty directories that need to be explicitly created during an installation. When "installing" the empty folder, the call to the `CurrentFileName` simply fails.

Workarounds:

- Remove the `createallsubdirs` flag, if possible.

  Instead, you can explicitly create empty directories using the [`[Dirs]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=dirssection).
- Catch the exception:

  ```pascal
  function FileBackup: Boolean; 
  begin 
    Result := True;
    try
      Source := ExpandConstant(CurrentFileName);
    except
      Log(GetExceptionMessage);
    end;
  end;
  ```

---

I have reported this on Inno Setup newsgroup, but the newsgroup was reset since.